# Is there a way to make the compiler include functions from outer scopes when picking a candidate?

Tags: c++, function, templates, scope

Consider this class and variadic member function:

```
class foo
{
public:
    template<class C, class... Cs>
    void add(C&& c, Cs&&... cs)
    {
        ...
        
        add(cs...);
    }
private:
    void add(){ }
};
```

Is there a way to place the empty `add` overload that terminates the recursion inside another scope? **Please ignore whether or not this is generally a good idea, I am strictly asking for how one could do it, if at all.** I would like to place it inside an `impl` namespace like so:

```
namespace impl
{
    void add() {}
}

class foo
{
public:
    template<class C, class... Cs>
    void add(C&& c, Cs&&... cs)
    {
        ...
        
        using namespace impl;
        add(cs...);
    }
};
```

But the above code does not work when instatiated. The compiler complains that it can't find a matching function call for `add` when the parameter pack is empty.

Is there a way to achieve this using some scope-hackery?

Comment: Have your empty `add()` overload simply call the other one, declared at the global scope, `void add() { impl::add(); }`? Problem solved!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The reason for wanting to put the empty `add` inside the `impl` namespace is to remove it from the class declaration, as it's completely irrelevant to users of the class. Sure that might be a little silly but as stated in the question I'm not asking about the approach of writing it like this. I just wanna know if it's possible.

Comment: No, it's not. C++'s overload resolution rules are quite strict, with no exceptions. And this happens to be precisely exactly what `private` class members are for: to declare stuff that's "irrelevant to users of the class". By making it private, you're making it irrelevant!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yeah, I guess. I can't really decide what the best approach for helper implementation functions is. With the empty `add` it's obviously pretty insignificant but I'm trying to choose a style and be consistent with it. When helper implementation functions start piling up, putting them all in the private field of the class declaration feels a little...ugly. It feels a bit off that users who just want to examine the class declaration are greeted with a bunch of implementation details. But this is obviously very subjective, I know a lot of people do as you suggest.

Comment: If this is a repeated design pattern then perhaps the correct solution is to refactor all the templated class members so that the recursion is handled by a single template, and all templates simply make use of it. The exact details, of course, depend on the actual implementations.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik After looking at 康桓瑋's answer, I just realized that I don't even need that empty function to terminate the recursion. I can just use `sizeof...` to check if the parameter pack is empty and if it is I stop calling the function. So my question is a bit irrelevant. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using `if constexpr`:

```
namespace impl { void add() {} }

class foo {
 public:
  template<class C, class... Cs>
  void add(C&& c, Cs&&... cs)
  {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Cs) == 0)
      impl::add();
    else
      add(cs...);
  }
};
```

Comment: Wow. Didn't realize I didn't even need that empty `add` overload to terminate the recursion. Had forgotten that you could check the size of a parameter pack with `sizeof...`. Since my empty `add` is completely empty - it doesn't do anything when called - I can just write `if constexpr (sizeof...(Cs) > 0) add(cs...);`

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
class foo_impl
{
    protected:
    void add() {}
};

class foo : private foo_impl
{
    using foo_impl::add;
public:
    template<class C, class... Cs>
    void add(C&& c, Cs&&... cs)
    {
        add(cs...);
    }
};
```

This will also work if `foo_impl` is placed in a separate namespace.

However, you can't make it work with `add()` as a free function. The only context in the language where member functions and free functions can belong to the same overload set is during overloaded operator lookup. This is because of the name lookup rules and the fact that overload resolution can only take place after name lookup, and only on the set of functions found by that name lookup.